# Waiver for 10 year ban

Tags: usa

I moved to usa when I was 12 years old. I had to leave when i was 25 due to my mothers health.  All those years i went to college and work, but i left illegaly.

Now I am stuck in south america with no family member, or profession. In Argentina i lost my house and is almost impossible finding a job. My degree is not acceptable here because i didnt certified it in the argentinian council. I dont have family member in the US  but i need to go back to keep studing. I am just wondering if i could apply for the waiver for the 10 year ban.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you in the US legally or illegally? If legally, what was your visa? If illegally, did the INS deport you or otherwise make note that you were staying illegally and give you a 10 year ban?

Comment: Mkennedy well i was in the US illegally and i didnt get deported.  I just left because i had little time.  I dont know about the INS  making note that i was illegally. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @mkennedy sorry forgot to tag you

Comment: Are you sure you're under a ban? Why not try to get a student visa?

Comment: @ElMatuIbanez How did you wind up in US at 12 years of age with your mother stuck in Argentina?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: next time you decide to enter a country illegally consider the consequences of your actions. You did the crime, now you suffer the consequences.

Comment: #jwenting  my mother took me when i was 12 and she left in 09 because of personal issues and culdnt como back because of the ban. So i didnt commit no crime.

Answer (score 1):

The exceptions to the 10-year-ban are as follows:

> 1. If you or your parents (while you were under 21 years of age) filed a permanent visa application with the Immigration and Naturalization
>      Service or Labor Department before April 30, 2001, you are protected
>      form this law and will be allowed to receive you Green Card in the
>      United States by paying a fine of $1,000. This is called Section
>      245(i) adjustment.
> 2. Children under 18 years of age;
> 3. Spouse children (under 21 years of age) and parents who entered with a visa;
> 4. Most people who filed a case with the Labor Department or the Immigration and Naturalization Service for Permanent Residency before
>      April 30, 2001.

Comment: Could you please add the source for your quoted text?

Comment: @mkennedy Apsan Law Offices web site

Comment: @LemuelGulliver Can you provide a link?